# How to get request body from from mock-server.org

Tags: mockserver

I am planning to use mock server from mock-server.org for a cypress project.
Is there any way to get requests body from the server so I can validate the schema and the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the received body in your expectation by setting something like the "regex body matcher":

```json
{
    "httpRequest": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/endpoint",
        "body": {
            "regex": ".*(this-should-be-there).*"
        }
    }
}
```

Then verify that this expectation has matched.

To validate schema, ou can use the "json schema body matcher".

See https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/jamesdbloom/mock-server-openapi/5.12.x#/Body to know all types of body you can validate.